# ExchangeService with AutodiscoverUrl sending from wrong email address

Tags: c#, outlook, active-directory, exchangewebservices

I am using this code to send an email via Outlook in a winforms application.

```
_exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
_exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(_sender);
// ...
var email = new EmailMessage(_exchangeService)
{
    Subject = mailMessage.Subject, 
    Body = mailMessage.Body
};
email.ToRecipients.AddRange(mailMessage.To.Select(x => x.Address));
email.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

I have put a breakpoint on `_exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(_sender);` and I can see that the sender is **customerservice@mycompany.com**.  However, the email is being sent "From" the actual user logged into the winforms app.  For example **person@mycompany.com**.

We have tried setting up Active Directory to "Send As" and "Send on Behalf" for this user to allow sending as customerservice@mycompany.com, but it did not help.  We have also reviewed the Exchange Server logging for this email and it is clearly being sent "From" person@mycompany.com.

In the code example here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634273, they use a `NetworkCredential`.  Do I need to do that?

Why is the sender (Email send **FROM**) wrong?

Comment: why don't you use `PrincipalContext` you can get the users email that way of the login user on the network.. the link you have attached uses network credentials so try it with that using the same example

Comment: @MethodMan I want to send the email **from** customerservice, not from the user's email address.

Comment: then can you add an entry into .config file or can you switch your code to use smtp  send email.. if you need a working example of that I can post it for you.. actually I know of a way that you could get it to work but I am not sure if this will do the trick I will post an answer in a sec

Comment: Cool.  I have changed to SMTP on another project, but I would prefer to fix this problem since Auto Discover will work regardless of server names.  (We recently had to re-deploy applications when the email server name changed, so that was not fun)

Comment: If you need to send with attachments just uncomment that portion of the code that I am posting

Comment: I also posted a SMTP method that totally works that I created yesterday for someone on Stackoverflow pay attention to how I am utilize the `using` it works like a charm btw you have a typo in your `mycomnpany` `customerservice@mycomnpany.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
_exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(_sender);
using email = new EmailMessage(_exchangeService)
{
    From = new MailAddress("customerservice@mycompany.com"),
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    //System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
    //attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("your attachment file");
    //mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    message.To.Add(address);//Jess@Jess.com for example
    _exchangeService.Send(message);
};
```

if you want a good method to SendEmail here is a Static Method I have created for you as well

```
public static void SendEmail(string subject, string body)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient(utilities.EmailHost, 25))
    using (var message = new MailMessage()
    {
        From = new MailAddress(utilities.FromEmail),
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    })
    {
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("your attachment file");
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        message.To.Add(address);//Jess@Jess.com for example
        client.Send(message);
    };
}
```

Comment: `client` is not defined in your first code snip.  Do you mean _exchangeService?  Man if I just have to set the `From` I think will will face palm.

Comment: Oh yeah .. sorry about that I will edit real quick @Jess

Comment: FYI Hope to try your solution today... got something else blocking ATM

Comment: the SMTP solution works very well I tested it many times and let me know also I think that the reason the original solution you wrote is not working the way you expect is because it's using the local users network credentials if you had an account setup with on Exchange with a service account or something then I think that would solve your issue..

Comment: Nailed it Mr. Man.  `From` was the answer.  Wow I can't believe it.  I thought the sender used to register the service would prevail, but I guess not.

Comment: I am glad that I was able to quickly spot the issue.. @Jess Have an awesome weekend